# Configure AutoFixture.AutoMoq to set DefaultValueProvider.Empty instead of DefaultValueProvider.Mock

Tags: .net, moq, mstest, autofixture, automoq

Somehow AutoFixture.AutoMoq is setting the property `DefaultValueProvider` of `Mock<T>` to `DefaultValueProvider.Mock` and I need to customize AutoFixture in a way that the value set is instead `DefaultValueProvider.Empty`.

I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Are you expecting the AutoMoqCustomization to configure the members?
e.g., `fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true })`?

Or are you only looking for AutoMoq to create raw Moq<T> instances when an interface is created?

Comment: @JeffDammeyer I am not setting ConfigureMembers to any value, so whatever comes by default is fine (I think it was `false`). What I've seen in the source code from AutoMoqCustomization class is that `DefaultValueProvider` is set to `Mock` regardless of the value of `ConfigureMembers` property.